# IndexError: list index out of range - beautiful soup find_all method

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing a personal project whereby I am trying to pull data from a football website.

I am currently faced with a setback that I cannot seem to be able to get over.

When I add a `break` statement at the end of the `for` loop of the `get_fixtures_data` function the code throws no error. When I remove the `break` statement, the code throws an `IndexError`. The line that seems to be throw an error suggests that the variable named `results` in the `get_fixtures_data` function which is a list has no elements. I used the `pycharm` debugger to figure out the point at which point the list has no elements. But I have not been successful in doing that. I cannot find the point where the size of the list is zero.

Here is my attempt to debugging the code. As you can see in the image, the size of the list is not zero.

[image: code debugging in pycharm]

The code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


class FootballPredictions:

    LEAGUES = ["https://www.flashscore.co.za/soccer/england/premier-league/fixtures/",
               "https://www.flashscore.co.za/soccer/spain/laliga/fixtures/",
               "https://www.flashscore.co.za/soccer/germany/bundesliga/fixtures/",
               "https://www.flashscore.co.za/soccer/italy/serie-a/fixtures/",
               "https://www.flashscore.co.za/soccer/brazil/serie-a/fixtures/",
               "https://www.flashscore.co.za/soccer/france/ligue-1/fixtures/",
               "https://www.flashscore.co.za/soccer/portugal/liga-portugal/fixtures/",
               "https://www.flashscore.co.za/soccer/mexico/liga-mx/fixtures/",
               "https://www.flashscore.co.za/soccer/argentina/liga-profesional/fixtures/",
               "https://www.flashscore.co.za/soccer/turkey/super-lig/fixtures/",
               ]

    @classmethod
    def get_fixtures_ids(cls):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless=new")
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

        day = datetime.today().day
        month = datetime.today().month
        # date = f"{day}.{month}."
        date = "01.04."

        for link in FootballPredictions.LEAGUES:
            browser.get(link)
            markup = browser.page_source

            soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")
            fixtures_divs = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "event__match event__match--static " +
                                                                 "event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"})

            for fixture in fixtures_divs:
                fixture_date = fixture.find_next("div", {"class": "event__time"}).text.split(" ")[0]
                fixture_id = fixture["id"].split("_")[-1]

                if date == fixture_date:
                    with open("ids.txt", "a") as file:
                        file.write(fixture_id + "\n")

        browser.quit()

    @classmethod
    def get_fixtures_data(cls):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless=new")
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

        with open("ids.txt", "r") as file:
            fixtures_identities = file.read().split("\n")[0:-1]

            for identity in fixtures_identities:
                fixture_identity = identity
                link = fr"https://www.flashscore.co.za/match/{fixture_identity}/#/h2h/overall"

                browser.get(link)
                markup = browser.page_source

                soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")

                teams = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "participant__participantName participant__overflow"})

                home_team = teams[0].text
                home_team_goals = 0

                away_team = teams[1].text
                away_team_goals = 0

                head_to_head_goals = 0

                results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "h2h__section section"})

                home_team_stats = results[0].find_all("div", {"class": "h2h__row"})
                away_team_stats = results[1].find_all("div", {"class": "h2h__row"})
                head_to_head_stats = results[2].find_all("div", {"class": "h2h__row"})

                # home team row
                for row in home_team_stats:
                    name = row.find("span", {"class": "h2h__homeParticipant"}).find("span", {"h2h__participantInner"})

                    if name.text == home_team:
                        goal = row.find("span", {"class": "h2h__result"}).find_all("span")[0].text
                        home_team_goals += int(goal)

                    else:
                        goal = row.find("span", {"class": "h2h__result"}).find_all("span")[1].text
                        home_team_goals += int(goal)

                # away team row
                for row in away_team_stats:
                    name = row.find("span", {"class": "h2h__homeParticipant"}).find("span", {"h2h__participantInner"})

                    if name.text == away_team:
                        goal = row.find("span", {"class": "h2h__result"}).find_all("span")[0].text
                        away_team_goals += int(goal)

                    else:
                        goal = row.find("span", {"class": "h2h__result"}).find_all("span")[1].text
                        away_team_goals += int(goal)

                # head-to-head row
                for row in head_to_head_stats:
                    home_goals = row.find("span", {"class": "h2h__result"}).find_all("span")[0].text
                    away_goals = row.find("span", {"class": "h2h__result"}).find_all("span")[1].text
                    goals = int(home_goals) + int(away_goals)
                    head_to_head_goals += goals

                # write data to file
                with open("fixtures_data.txt", "a") as data_file:
                    data_file.write(f"{home_team},{away_team},{home_team_goals},{away_team_goals},{head_to_head_goals}"
                                    + "\n")


    @classmethod
    def clear_files(cls):
        with open("ids.txt", "w") as file:
            pass

        with open("fixtures_data.txt", "w") as file:
            pass

        with open("predictions.txt", "w") as file:
            pass

    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        # FootballPredictions.get_fixtures_ids()
        FootballPredictions.get_fixtures_data()
        # FootballPredictions.clear_files()


FootballPredictions.run()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\FootballPredictions\main.py", line 81, in get_fixtures_data
    home_team_stats = results[0].find_all("div", {"class": "h2h__row"})
                      ~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It says list index out of range it means list is none. It can be for some urls just use `try`function for avoiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using try:

```
for identity in fixtures_identities:
            try:
                fixture_identity = identity
                link = 

fr"https://www.flashscore.co.za/match/{fixture_identity}/#/h2h/overall"

            browser.get(link)
            markup = browser.page_source

            soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")

            teams = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "participant__participantName participant__overflow"})

            home_team = teams[0].text
            home_team_goals = 0

            away_team = teams[1].text
            away_team_goals = 0

            head_to_head_goals = 0

            results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "h2h__section section"})

            home_team_stats = results[0].find_all("div", {"class": "h2h__row"})
            away_team_stats = results[1].find_all("div", {"class": "h2h__row"})
            head_to_head_stats = results[2].find_all("div", {"class": "h2h__row"})
        except:
            None
```